# laravel socialite is not installing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to install laravel Socialite, but it's not installing. I am using the basic installation command

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

But it's giving me the following error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.4 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.5 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - laravel/socialite v3.0.6 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.3.26, required as 5.3.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.26].
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have successfully implemented the default laravel authentication, and it works without any issue. I don't what's the problem with this one...

Comment: The error seems clear:socialite requires laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

`- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.3.26, required as 5.3.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.26].`

It happens because you lock your `laravel/laravel` to version `5.3.26`, but `laravel/socialite` you wish to install require `illuminate/support` version `~5.4`, which is in `laravel/laravel` version `~5.4`, too.

Possible solution:

1. use `laravel/socialite` version `~2.0` (by executing `composer require laravel/socialite:~2.0`), it meets your `laravel/laravel` version you currently use.
2. if you really, really need to use `laravel/socialite` version `~3.0`, you have to upgrade your `laravel/laravel` to version `~5.4` by executing `composer require laravel/laravel:~5.4`